# What does the last phrase 'when a sphere' mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrases

link to the book [At the Mountains of Madness](http://www.hplovecraft.com/writings/texts/fiction/mm.aspx)

I encountered this sentence and can only guess what it means, but I want to know for sure

> They were normally shapeless entities composed of a viscous jelly which looked like an agglutination of bubbles; and *each averaged about fifteen feet in diameter **when a sphere***. They had, however, a constantly shifting shape and volume; throwing out temporary developments or forming apparent organs of sight, hearing, and speech in imitation of their masters, either spontaneously or according to suggestion.

---

Question

Does the phrase *'when a sphere' - when you deal with a sphere* mean? If not - I appreciate the right answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can understand it to mean "when it took/had the shape of a sphere" Compare: *He practiced many arts, poetry, painting, music, theater, but most people would say he did his best work **when a painter***.  In other words, "when [being] a painter".

The amorphous entity was constantly changing its shape. Every now and then it would assume the approximate shape of a sphere. At such moments, its diameter was about fifteen feet.

> The UFO was constantly changing shape. Sometimes the UFO was round
>   like a hamburger, and sometimes it was elongated like a sausage.  **When
>   a hamburger**, its diameter was about fifty feet.